# Access next, previous, or current row in pandas .loc[] assignment

Tags: python, pandas

Under the if-then section of the pandas documentation [cookbook](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#if-then), we can assign values in one column, based on a condition being met for a separate column using `loc[]`.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [4,5,6,7], 
'BBB' : [10,20,30,40],
'CCC' : [100,50,-30,-50]})
#    AAA  BBB  CCC
# 0    4   10  100
# 1    5   20   50
# 2    6   30  -30
# 3    7   40  -50

df.loc[df.AAA >= 5,'BBB'] = -1
#    AAA  BBB  CCC
# 0    4   10  100
# 1    5   -1   50
# 2    6   -1  -30
# 3    7   -1  -50
```

But what if I want to write a condition that involves the previous or subsequent row using `.loc[]`? For example, say I want to assign `df.BBB=5` wherever the difference between the `df.CCC` of the current row and the `df.CCC` of the next row is greater than or equal to 50. Then I would like to create a condition that gives me the following data frame:

```
#    AAA  BBB  CCC
# 0    4    5  100 <-| 100 - 50 = 50, assign df.BBB = 5
# 1    5    5   50 <-| 50 -(-30)= 80, assign df.BBB = 5 
# 2    6   -1  -30 <-| 30 -(-50)= 20, don't assign df.BBB = 5
# 3    7   -1  -50 <-| (-50) -0 =-50, don't assign df.BBB = 5
```

How can I get this result?

**Edit**
The answer I'm hoping to find is something like

```
mask = df['CCC'].current - df['CCC'].next >= 50
df.loc[mask, 'BBB'] = 5
```

because I'm interested in the general problem of how I can access values above or below the current row being considered in a dataframe.(not necessarily solving this one toy example.)

`diff()` will work on the example I first described, but what of other cases, say, where we want to compare two elements instead of subtracting them?

What if I take the previous data frame and I want to find all rows where the current column entry doesn't match the next in `df.BBB` and then assign `df.CCC` based on those comparisons?

```
if df.BBB.current == df.CCC.next:
    df.CCC = 1

#    AAA  BBB  CCC     
# 0    4    5    1 <-|  5 ==  5, assign df.CCC = 1
# 1    5    5   50 <-|  5 != -1, do nothing
# 2    6   -1    1 <-| -1 == -1, assign df.CCC = 1
# 3    7   -1  -50 <-| -1 !=  0, do nothing
```

Is there a way to do this with pandas using `.loc[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
>>> df
   AAA  BBB  CCC
0    4   10  100
1    5   20   50
2    6   30  -30
3    7   40  -50
```

you can compute a boolean mask first via

```
>>> mask = df['CCC'].diff(-1) >= 50
>>> mask
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: CCC, dtype: bool
```

and then issue

```
>>> df.loc[mask, 'BBB'] = 5
>>> 
>>> df
   AAA  BBB  CCC
0    4    5  100
1    5    5   50
2    6   30  -30
3    7   40  -50
```

---

More generally, you can compute a shift

```
>>> df['CCC_next'] = df['CCC'].shift(-1) # or df['CCC'].shift(-1).fillna(0)
>>> df
   AAA  BBB  CCC  CCC_next
0    4    5  100      50.0
1    5    5   50     -30.0
2    6   30  -30     -50.0
3    7   40  -50       NaN
```

... and then do whatever you want, such as:

```
>>> df['CCC'].sub(df['CCC_next'], fill_value=0)
0    50.0
1    80.0
2    20.0
3   -50.0
dtype: float64
>>> mask = df['CCC'].sub(df['CCC_next'], fill_value=0) >= 50
>>> mask
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

although for the specific problem in your question the `diff` approach is sufficient.

Comment: The boolean series created by `df['CCC'].diff(-1) >= 50` does work for this example. Although, I am looking to access previous and subsequent elements generally. `diff()` takes the difference between the current and subsequent elements for us; I want to do the same, but directly. I'll edit my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate function to access row and its index simultaneously. Thus you can obtain previous and next row based on the index of the current row. I provide an example script below for your reference:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [4,5,6,7],
                   'BBB' : [10,20,30,40],
                   'CCC' : [100,50,-30,-50]}, index=['a','b','c','d'])

print('row_pre','row_pre_AAA','row','row_AA','row_next','row_next_AA')
for irow, row in enumerate(df.index):
    if irow==0:
        row_next = df.index[irow+1]
        print('row_pre', "df.loc[row_pre,'AAA']", row, df.loc[row,'AAA'], row_next, df.loc[row_next,'AAA'])
    elif irow>0 and irow<df.index.size-1:
        row_pre = df.index[irow-1]
        row_next = df.index[irow+1]
        print(row_pre, df.loc[row_pre,'AAA'], row, df.loc[row,'AAA'], row_next, df.loc[row_next,'AAA'])
    else:
        row_pre = df.index[irow-1]
        print(row_pre, df.loc[row_pre,'AAA'], row, df.loc[row,'AAA'], 'row_next', "df.loc[row_next,'AAA']")
```

Output as below:

```
row_pre row_pre_AAA row row_AA row_next row_next_AA
row_pre df.loc[row_pre,'AAA'] a 4 b 5
a 4 b 5 c 6
b 5 c 6 d 7
c 6 d 7 row_next df.loc[row_next,'AAA']
```