# Grouping consecutively timed rows into sessions pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have logged user data from a video platform and need to group consecutively watched videos into sessions. The data looks like this:

```
        user_id     pid             view_time    
724117  2755025951  84142247679     2022-09-17 12:31:35     
724051  2755025951  84049359330     2022-09-17 12:35:01 
724179  2755025951  84206528723     2022-09-17 12:37:43 
723968  2755025951  83893305120     2022-09-17 12:45:04     
724000  2755025951  83963063552     2022-09-17 12:49:15
```

For simplicity, let's say I want to group all rows watched within a 5 minute interval (i.e. less than 5 minutes after the previous video). Then, the resulting data would count the number of videos in the given session and give the start time of that session, as such:

```
        user_id   session_start_time    number_of_videos    
724117  2755025951  2022-09-17 12:31:35     3   
723445  2755025951  2022-09-17 12:45:04     2
```

I have tried to iterating through dataframe using `iterrows()` and comparing the timestamp of a certain row with the following row, but the best I can get is only two rows into one session (i.e. the trouble is recursively iterating an indefinite number of the subsequent rows to check whether they are within 5 minutes, rather than checking them against a specific row). I have also tried using `shift` (as per this answer: [Access next, previous, or current row in pandas .loc[] assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53694241/access-next-previous-or-current-row-in-pandas-loc-assignment)), but this runs into the same issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm not particularly new. I just happen to ask few questions :') (thanks for the advice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create groups based on `view_time` columns:

```
# If necessary
df['view_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['view_time'])

view_grp = df.groupby('user_id')['view_time'].diff().gt('5min').cumsum()
out = (df.groupby(['user_id', view_grp], as_index=False)
         .agg(session_start_time=('view_time', 'first'),
              number_of_videos=('view_time', 'size')))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
      user_id  session_start_time  number_of_videos
0  2755025951 2022-09-17 12:31:35                 3
1  2755025951 2022-09-17 12:45:04                 2
```

Details:

```
diff = df.groupby('user_id')['view_time'].diff().rename('diff')
group = diff.gt('5min').cumsum().rename('group')
pd.concat([df, diff, group], axis=1)

# Output
           user_id          pid           view_time            diff  group
724117  2755025951  84142247679 2022-09-17 12:31:35             NaT      0
724051  2755025951  84049359330 2022-09-17 12:35:01 0 days 00:03:26      0
724179  2755025951  84206528723 2022-09-17 12:37:43 0 days 00:02:42      0
723968  2755025951  83893305120 2022-09-17 12:45:04 0 days 00:07:21      1
724000  2755025951  83963063552 2022-09-17 12:49:15 0 days 00:04:11      1
```

Comment: I'm getting an issue here: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` for the `groupby` statement. Not exactly sure what's going on...

Comment: Did you convert `view_time` column as `DatetimeIndex`? Try `df['view_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['view_time'])`

Comment: The classic time format conversion. It worked! Many thanks.

Comment: FYI I actually had to set `as_index=True` to get what I wanted. For some reason, the aggregated columns were not coming out as intended otherwise.